# Can I use old engine oil to protect tools from rusting?

Tags: tools, rust

I'm not sure if the question is on-topic here, since it's about tools and not exactly mechanics, but if it's not I can move it to the appropriate SE!

I have a power drill and used it once at work to fix a problem we had there. It was used close to an oxidizing chemical and I believe because of that the folder head started rusting a little bit. Before it got too serious I used sandpaper and removed the superficial rust, then applied rust converter (it doesn't look much pretty now since the rust converter creates a black layer, but I'm more concerned about protecting it).

There are some types of oil that are also used to prevent corrosion and I have some old engine oil here. I was wondering if I applied just a little bit of it, if it would also help prevent rust from coming back.

Comment: Rust is like cancer, you can put it in remission for a while but always comes back if not treated regularly.

Comment: for something easy to find locally, WD40 300035 corrosion inhibitor has given me excellent results on my car chassis in Minnesota winter driving conditions. CRC 6026 is better but harder to find

Comment: @Moab I'm trying to treat it while it's still early and superficial. Learned my lesson, not using my tools for that kind of stuff anymore. I didn't even drop the chemical on my power drill, think just the small amounts of it on air was enough. I'll keep an eye if it stopped now

Comment: @RichieFrame I thought about it just earlier! I have a can with a little of WD40 on it, going to put it to use now!

Comment: That  is the one legitimate use of WD-40.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don’t use old engine oil - it has lots of contaminants in it.

Use a fine layer of clean oil - just a drop or two spread with a rag is sufficient.

Comment: addendum, depending on how used the oil is it can actually be more corrosive to metal than the air

Comment: @RichieFrame I **used** to use old engine oil for lubricating the chains on chainsaws - I don’t do that anymore!!! And don’t advise it at all.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it was that bad. A while back I used it for lubricating the chains on my motorcycle, it never rusted probably because the chain is very resistant to corrosion, I only did it a couple of times and its lifetime is probably short enough so I wouldn't see the damage. But now that you alerted me, I'm not doing it anymore, actually haven't done in a while since I found some appropriate chain paste